# rxjs: conditional take number

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this function that returns an observable that emits a deviceId and its related MediaStream:

```
 private getStreamToDeviceId(deviceKind: "audioinput" | "videoinput") {
    return from(navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()).pipe(
      map((devices) =>
        devices
          .filter((device) => device.kind === deviceKind)
          .map((device) => device.deviceId)
      ),
      take(1),
      concatMap((deviceIds) => of(...deviceIds)),
      concatMap((deviceId) =>
        zip(
          of(deviceId),
          from(
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
              audio: deviceKind === "audioinput" ? { deviceId } : false,
              video: deviceKind === "videoinput" ? { deviceId } : false,
            })
          ).pipe(take(1))
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```

I would like to put a `take(devicesNumber)` at the end, but, if I try to set `devicesNumber` into a tap right after the `take(1)`, it doesn't work.

How can I do it?

Also, are those `take(1)` I used really helpful to automatically unsubscribe?

Comment: It's difficult to know what you are trying to achieve. Take unsubscribes after 1 emission. You're wrapping a promise so you don't really need the second take() since promises only ever emit and complete once.

Comment: Good to know about the `take(1)`. What I am trying to achieve is to complete the observable once all zips have been fired. The streams are obtained only once when the application is started

Comment: That happens by default if i'm not mistaken. When you subscribe to the result of your function. It will fire the call and then complete when all the inner observables are finished. Your first `take(1)` will cause only one emission as well. The streams are only taken once because they originate from promises which will only ever complete once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a number or a variable into `take`.

Also, once you use tap after a `take(1)`, tap won't be active.

Another thing is that a `tap` is a **side effect** which means that you cannot propagate the assigned value inside a tap to an operator.

If you need a conditioned `take`, then you should use `takeUntil` or `takeWhile`.

Now, specifically for your question, you are using `take` the wrong way.

Here is `zip` definition: **After all observables emit, emit values as an array**.

That means that if all obervables have been emitted and you have the final emitted array, then you should be good with `take(1)` because the process is automatic.

There is no need to worry about the `take(devicesCounter)`.

Also, if you do not care about the final result as an array, you could use `forkJoin`.

`forkJoin` is **when all observables complete, emit the last emitted value from each**.

It means that you already know that all of the observables are completed and therefore you can use `take(1)` with no worries right after the `forkJoin`.

To sum up, your current code works fine and you don't need to worry for irrelevant `take(number)`